# What is the way to set UTF-8 or other encoding in .zshrc on MacOS Catalina?

Tags: macos, zsh, macos-catalina

Whatever settings I put in .zshrc and source the file, nothing changes in the locale output. How do I change these settings on Catalina?

Answer (score 0):

You should not have to set these manually. The OS will set them for you. If you do want to change them, then you should do so in System Preferences.